# Where can I find the official 'Available in Android Market' icon?

Tags: android, icons, google-play

Is there more than one version? I have seen a green and a black version. I also saw a green 'shopping bag' version. Which icon is officially accepted by Google for developers to advertise the app on their blogs or websites?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find it here: http://www.android.com/branding.html

Answer (score 2):

Right [here](http://www.android.com/branding.html). Theres the updated one there.